# url_for in flask - multiple parameters - TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
@app.route('/quiz/<quiz_id>/<question_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def quiz(quiz_id, question_id): 
    quiz = Quiz.query.filter_by(id=quiz_id).first()
    qa = Question.query.filter_by(quiz_id=quiz_id).filter_by(id=question_id).first()
    length = Question.query.filter_by(quiz_id=quiz_id).count()

    if request.method =='POST':
        test = request.form[str(question_id)]
        ufq=UserFilledQuiz(user_id=current_user.id, quiz_id=quiz_id, question_id = question_id, \
        answer = request.form[str(question_id)])
        db.session.add(ufq)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template(url_for('quiz', quiz_id=1, question_id=1), title='Quiz', quiz=quiz, qa=qa, length=length)

    return render_template('quiz.html', title='Quiz', quiz=quiz, qa=qa, length=length)
```

Hi,
i want to use one view to make quiz in which one site is one question and answers.
If i write links by hand for example quiz/1/1 or quiz/1/2 - it works.
If i submit form with answer i recieve message: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /quiz/1/1` When i press enter in url bar it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line `return render_template(url_for('quiz', quiz_id=1, question_id=1), title='Quiz', quiz=quiz, qa=qa, length=length)`, the call to `url_for` should be replaced with the name of the actual template, much like `'quiz.html'` on the line below..

---

For a further diagnosis of the issue you're having here:

When you enter the URL manually, you're sending a GET request and hitting the lower `render_template` which renders a template called `quiz.html` (which presumably exists, since there is no error). So far so good.

On making a POST request by submitting a form, you're hitting the upper `render_template`, which has `url_for` in its first parameter. Since you're accessing the page `/quiz/1/1`, this is equivalent to writing `'/quiz/1/1'` as the name of the template in the `render_template` call. It seems obvious that this is incorrect.